# Create EventSystem from script

Tags: events, unity-game-engine, event-handling, game-engine

I'm writing a Unity editor script and need to make sure that an (UI) Event System exists so I want to create one if it's not already there. But the `EventSystem` class and `StandaloneInputModule` class can nowhere be found when trying to import it to a script. What's the matter with this? I can't find any other info on this matter either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add an UI item, the EventSystem object is automatically added. Just drag it into your Project to make it a prefab so you can use it to be instantiated just like any game object.

```c#
public GameObject eventPrefab;
void Start(){
    if(GameObject.Find("EventSystem") == null){
         Instantiate(eventPrefab);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, creating a prefab and instantiating it is probably a good workaround. Thanks for the tip! It's still strange that those classes cannot be added to a game object via script, though.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can create an `EventSystem` from the script. As any other component, create a `GameObject` and add the desired component to it.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class CreateEventSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        if (FindObjectOfType<EventSystem>() == null)
        {
            var eventSystem = new GameObject("EventSystem", typeof(EventSystem), typeof(StandaloneInputModule));
        }
    }
}
```